# Ruby on rails submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

am new in ruby on rails and please i want to execute a method in my controller or in my helper when i click this button, so any ideas for that?

```
<%= button_to 'Export POINT',  :action => :create_file_txt %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a javascript method? You can't directly run Rails code from the browser. You must create a controller that takes a request and then your button must in some way call this controller action. Maybe you should describe in more detail what you actually want to do.

Comment: rather then specifying a button, use a link.

Comment: in my index.html.erb

    <%= button_to 'Export POINT', :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'create_file_txt' %>

in my_contoller 

    def create_file_txt 
.
.
end

init.rb

    permission :view_button_exp, {:controller => :my_controller, :action => :create_file_txt}, :require => :member

That's what i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Route**

[`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) is basically a link:

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL
>   created by the set of options. This is the safest method to ensure
>   links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by search bots
>   or accelerators. If the HTML button does not work with your layout,
>   you can also consider using the link_to method with the :method
>   modifier as described in the link_to documentation

You need to send it to a [route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
#config/routes.rb
get "your_route", to: "controller#action"
```

This will give you the ability to use the [URL helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) to define the path & get the button to work:

```
<%= button_to 'Export POINT',  your_route_path %>
```

---

**Link**

As per the comments, you would also benefit from using [`link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) for this as well:

```
<%= link_to 'Export POINT',  your_route_path %>
```